# backdrop-filter in combination with mask-image doesn't work as expected on chrome

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a certain problem with the two attributes `mask-image` and `backdrop-filter` in combination on Chrome v116.

I am trying to render a gradient-blur effect over a text. In Firefox this works fine but on Chrome only a white solid block is rendered.

This is how it should look (Firefox v116):

[image]

This is how it looks instead (Chrome v116):

[image]

Heres the code im using:

```html
<div class="gradient-blur" *ngIf="checkOverflowBlurGradient(container)">
</div>
```

```css
.gradient-blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #F8F9FA);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #F8F9FA);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I checked on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) and chrome v116 is actually supported according to the documentation.

Now I am wondering if this problem is somehow caused by my browser or implementation related.

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the problem!

Comment: I actually already fixed it, im gonna provide an answer with what fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed it myself. Apparently `backdrop-filter` in combination with `mask-image` is not really the best to get a continuous behavior on all browsers. So I tried `mask: conic-gradient` and got a pretty consistent result, which clearly looks better than my previous approach.

Here is the code i used:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  mask: conic-gradient(from 90deg at 0px 0px, #0000 25%, #000 0) 0px 0px,
    linear-gradient(#000 70%, #0000 95%);
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(from 90deg at 0px 0px, #0000 25%, #000 0) 0px 0px,
    linear-gradient(#000 20%, #0000 95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div
```

Additionaly heres a little [CodePen](https://codepen.io/schtucks/pen/rNoNMKr).

Answer (score -1):

Weirdly, I've been able to work around this in Chrome by *removing* `overflow: hidden` on the container. The overflowing text in your examples may prove tricky without that, though, and I also can't explain why it works in your CodePen *with* an `overflow`.

Comment: i posted an answer, already fixed it.